# Double win10 installs - both bitlocker protected and isolated

Tags: windows, privacy, truecrypt, bitlocker, boot

Hardware:

- AMD Ryzen processor, ASUS Crosshair Hero VI mb, no TPM installed
- M.2 Samsung 960 PRO SSD
- SATA Samsung 840 PRO SSD

I would like to have latest win10 2004 on both SSDs and isolated from one another for privacy reasons.

- 1st SSD is for work and part of AzureAD
- 2nd SSD should be private

M.2 is already installed, with bitlocker and working. Asking for PIN on boot (before OS menu).

When I tried to setup bitlocker on 2nd SSD bitlocker setup crashed and cannot boot to 2nd OS anymore.
TrueCrypt is also an alternative for 2nd SSD, but seems I will have same problems with bootloaders?

Any suggestions how to set this up?
If really necessary I will reinstall everything.